# I want to Highlight the selected tab in Navbar on React BootStrap

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, navbar, react-bootstrap, use-state

I want to simply highlight the tab selected from the `NavBar`. I had used the `Navbar Component of React-bootstrap` and used the state to change the `bgColor` and `textColor` of the selected tab. But it is still NOT working? Any corrections?

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { Navbar,Container, Nav } from "react-bootstrap"
import { LogOut } from "./LogOut"

const NavbarComponent = () => {

const [bgcolor, setBgcolor] = useState('black');
const [textcolor, setTextcolor] = useState('white');    

function handleHighlightTab() {
    setBgcolor('white');
    setTextcolor('black');
} 

return (
    <>
    <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" fixed='top' className='nav-pills'>
        <Container>
            <Navbar.Brand href="/">Verticals</Navbar.Brand>
            <Nav className="me-auto">
                <Nav.Link href="/grocery" onSelect={handleHighlightTab} style={{backgroundColor:{bgcolor},color:{textcolor} }} >Grocery</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/fashion" onSelect={handleHighlightTab} style={{backgroundColor:{bgcolor},color:{textcolor} }} >Fashion</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/footwear" onSelect={handleHighlightTab} style={{backgroundColor:{bgcolor},color:{textcolor} }}>Footwear</Nav.Link>
         
            </Nav>
            <LogOut />
        </Container>
    </Navbar>

    </>
)
}

export default NavbarComponent;
```

Comment: What do you see at the moment?

Comment: They are not highlighted once they are selected

Comment: Could you attache the image here?

Comment: Its just a simple NavBar taken from here https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/  
I have taken the dark navbar

Comment: See my answer if it works for you